# Python FastApi GET loop

Tags: python

Good day for everyone, its my first request in this service, so i am glad to see all of you^^

I am have some trouble with FastApi.

I have raspberry pi 3, and barcode scanner with USB interface, i now how get data with while loop, but i am need to get this data from request, so i am write async script for this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from services.barcode import barcode_reader

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"], allow_credentials=True, allow_methods=["*"], allow_headers=["*"])
barcode = ""

async def get_barcode():
    try:
        while True:
            # barcode = barcode_reader()
            if barcode != "":
                return barcode
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

@app.get("/barcode")
async def read_barcode():
    return await get_barcode()
    

@app.post("/barcode/{barcodeStr}")
async def write_barcode(barcodeStr: str):
    barcode = barcodeStr
    return "success"
```

But when I make a GET request, I cannot put data with a POST request, in the future I will have many more methods that will be executed constantly and I would not like one method to block the entire API.

Help me please ^^

Comment: I have the same problem. But I need to get an event loop to include a telegram bot there

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code you've provided, I'm not sure how you expect the barcode reader to work. You're not providing it with input, so I can't see how it would be able to process the barcode.

You are taking in the `barcodeStr` path parameter in your `POST` route, so I'm assuming that's how you want your service to work. It also seems that your `get_barcode` coroutine doesn't use return a Future or Task. In that case, you're correct in that it would most likely be a blocking operation.

If your barcode reader service is calling an external API or is an IO-bound function in general, then using the `async/await` syntax can avoid blocking the event loop.

Your code could potentially be re-written like so:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from services.barcode import barcode_reader

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware, 
    allow_origins=["*"], 
    allow_credentials=True, 
    allow_methods=["*"], 
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

async def process_barcode(barcode_str: str) -> int:
    """
    Assume this returns a product id.
    """
    try:
        while True:
            barcode_id = await barcode_reader(barcode_str)
            if barcode_id:
                return barcode_id
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    

@app.post("/barcode/{barcodeStr}", response_model=int)
async def write_barcode(barcodeStr: str):
    product_id = await process_barcode(barcodeStr)
    return product_id
```